# How do I subtract the asterisks in a descending order on my code?

Tags: python

I want the marble dots to be displayed in the output, and as the number of marbles go down, so do the asterisks. I don't know what command will have the asterisks descend as the while loop runs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

marbles = 10  #You start out with 10 marbles
marble_dots = "**********" #Pretend these are ten marbles

while (marbles > 0):
   print(marble_dots[:10])

   #This prints out how many marbles you have left.
   # We have to say str(marbles) because marbles is a number
   # and we want to use it in a string (letters and other characters)
   print("You have " + str(marbles) + " marbles left.")

   if (marbles < 4):
       print("Warning: You are running low on marbles!!")

   #This is another way of saying "Subtract 1 from the marbles variable"
   # It is logically the same as writing "marbles = marbles - 1", just shorter
   marbles -= 1

   # Make a newline, so there's an empty line before the next time we run this loop
   print("")
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my question looks badly formatted this is my first time posting here. the "#" are from my prompt

Comment: What are you trying to do, are you trying to make it print forever? Are you taking input from the user, try to be more descriptive, what’s your goal and what errors are you getting?

Comment: the code is supposed to display as such: ******* You have 10 marbles left, ******* you have 9 marbles left, ********* you have 8 marbles left etc. I need the asteriks to decrease 1 asterik every time the number of marbles decrease. Hope that explains it a lil bit.

Answer (score 5):

Nearly there!

Just change the print from hard-coded `10` to the number of marbles remaining

```
while (marbles > 0):
   
   print(marble_dots[:marbles])
```

You could also replace it with:

```
print('*' * marbles)
```

Which will print * once per marble.

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate your time, I hope blessings come your way.

Comment: @jack if it answered your question please mark the answer as accepted,  so people know the question is solved (and I get some imaginary internet points.)